# numpy How to reduce computation time by converting 64-bit data to 32-bit or lower dtypes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, types

Does converting 64-bit int and float data to 32-bit or the lowest possible dtype that can handle all the data improve numpy computational speed? Are there reasons *not* to do this?

I have two pandas dataframes, each with ~5 million rows and 23 columns containing `str`, `int`, `datetime`, `float`, and `timedelta` datatype. Here's an abbreviated sample row that includes the various datatypes (see below for code to recreate):

```
    group  job_number  submission_time      maxvmem       wait_time
0   g1     3912841     2018-09-29 16:03:49  4.040196e+09  1 days 15:49:38
```

I am considering mapping the nonnumerics to numerics and creating a numpy ndarray to speed processing.

My question is about the further step of minimizing the bit size of datatypes. I ask because I have rarely / maybe never seen this step taken in solutions I've read on SO or seen in tutorials. This makes me wonder if there are reasons **not** to do this and to simply let numpy handle what dtype to use.

---

**MVCE**

Here's my attempt at code to recreate the sample row above. It seems to work except for the `timedelta` assignment. When I run this I get `ValueError: Could not convert object to NumPy timedelta`. I'd update if someone can tell me how to make that work.:

```
sample_row = pd.DataFrame([['g1', 3912841, '2018-09-29 16:03:49', 4.040196e+09, '1 days 15:49:38']], columns=['group','job_number', 'submission_time', 'maxvmem', 'wait_time'])
sample_row = (sample_row.astype(dtype={'group':'str', 'job_number':'int', 'submission_time':'datetime64[ns]', 'maxvmem':'float', 'wait_time':'timedelta64[ns]'}))
```

Comment: In a `pandas` dateframe you probably have a mix of dtypes.  Your concern with 32 v 64 only applies to the numeric Series.  You'd have to be doing so heavy math to see a difference, and even then it probaby will be marginal.  It doesn't apply to strings.  Pandas stores those a `object` anyways.

Comment: Right. I was thinking of mapping the strings to ints for purposes of computation (some of the columns only have 10 or so different values), then reading the mapped strings back in at the end for presentation.

Comment: In other words, map everything that isn't already a float to float, convert all values to the lowest bit-size dtype that covers all the values, convert df to ndarray, compute, and convert back to df with original values in place of floats. Seems like a lot of work, but some of the processes I'm running on these long df's take 20 min to 2 hrs each, so looking for ways to speed them up.

Comment: Without more information about the computation(s) it will be hard to assess, or test, your ideas.

Comment: Ultimately I need to compare df_1 and df_2 and remove any overlapping rows. I.e., if a rows exists in both df's, remove it from both df's. The result is df_1 contains only the rows that are unique to df_1 and df_2 contains only the rows that are unique to df_2.

Comment: Comparison code: `u = df_1.merge(df_2, how='outer', indicator=True)`  . . . 
`df_3 = u.query('_merge == "left_only"').drop('_merge', 1)` . . . 
`df_4 = u.query('_merge == "right_only"').drop('_merge', 1)`

Comment: [Here](https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2017/05/08/half-precision-16-bit-floating-point-arithmetic/)'s a MATLAB-related post about lower precisions. It focuses on half-precision, but there's plenty of explanation about higher-bit representations and accuracy (or lack thereof).

Comment: Changing the strings (which are objects in `pandas` to one-hot probably will help, but I doubt if changing the `int` and `float` column dtype will make comparing rows any faster.  The time columns don't have a 32bit equivalents.  This isn't a computationally heavy operation, at least not of the kind that `numpy` excels. in.

Comment: Note that instead of one-hot you can probably use pandas categoricals.

Comment: @AndrasDeak, thanks, I'll keep pandas categoricals in mind.

Comment: @AndrasDeak, and thanks for the post on lower precisions. I recently saw a Forbes article from around the same time (2017) that mentioned the coming NVIDIA GPUs that would support half precision floats.

Comment: Yes, and the main message of the post is that anything below single-precision is silly ;)

Comment: If you only need to compare things, then I am skeptical that your question is relevant. The task you have is a O(n) hash computation followed by a hash set intersection , followed by a hopefully by now small o(n**2) comparision step. Moving everyhing to lower precision is another o(n) step. Your core algorithm is not doing intense work on the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Halving the bit depth from 64 to 32 will halve your memory usage.

The most common [performance bottleneck](https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832) for compute intensive code is memory bandwidth and cache usage.

It is likely that your performance will improve significantly if you are compute bound.

However do not do computation with 32 bits. Instead, promote them to 64 in code that does lots of math. With 32 floats you will hit [numerical issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error) faster.

I strongly advise against using [16 bit floats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format) for any computation.

EDIT

Your example has variable data types like strings. My answer becomes less relevant if you don't have pure numpy numerical arrays.

Comment: Thank you. My idea is to map the nonnumerics to numerics, that is replace the strings with numeric representations a la one-hot encoding. That way I could create a homogeneous, all-numeric multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Can you explain why not to compute with 32-bit (or 16 or 8) values? Or rather, what are the "numerical issues" that will arise? I'm fine keeping everything 64-bit, just want to understand why that is best practice rather than taking it on faith!

Comment: You are right I rushed my answer. If you only store data then I see no problem in storing it in low precision if you dont need the extra precision. However, later you might want to do computation with the low precision data. Such math tends to reduce the precision of the results. If you are in 16 bit floats regular math may make you loose most precision bits.

Comment: Huh, that's interesting, that the objects would lose their precision bits. I'll have to do some more reading on that. Thanks!